# What does the error message mean?

Tags: sql-server

I created (copied from the Internet) a batch file for backing up my database 'WIS':

```
echo off
cls
echo -- BACKUP DATABASE --
set /p DATABASENAME=WIS

:: filename format Name-Date (eg MyDatabase-2009.5.19.bak)
set DATESTAMP=%DATE:~-4%.%DATE:~7,2%.%DATE:~4,2%
set BACKUPFILENAME=%CD%\%DATABASENAME%-%DATESTAMP%.bak
set SERVERNAME=WIN2016
echo.

sqlcmd -E -S %SERVERNAME% -d master -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [%DATABASENAME%] TO DISK = N'%BACKUPFILENAME%' WITH INIT , NOUNLOAD , NAME = N'%DATABASENAME% backup', NOSKIP , STATS = 10, NOFORMAT"
echo.
pause
```

However I got the following error message when I ran the batch file.

> Msg 1038, Level 15, State 4, Server WIN2016, Line 1
>   An object or column name is missing or empty. For `SELECT INTO` statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as `""` or `[]` are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.

Could anyone tell me is wrong with this code?

Comment: Replace `sqlcmd` with `echo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
set /p DATABASENAME=WIS
```

to

```
set DATABASENAME=WIS
```

That may help.

Comment: I follow your instruction to delete the system shows: Cannot open backup device 'F:\Tmp\new\WIS-2017.01.1/.bak'

Comment: How can I change 2017.01.1/.bak to the 2017-01-04.bak?

Comment: I found the solution myself. It is set DATESTAMP=%DATE:~6,4%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2%

Comment: One more question. Does the %Date variable depend on the format setting of the Windows?

Comment: I guess it must be. Thus no need to answer.

Comment: Yes, as you already figured out: it is dependent of the Windows settings for date format..